# PHP escape unescaped quote marks

Tags: php, str-replace

I know I can use the following to replace " with \":

```
str_replace('"', '\"', $string);
```

But if some quotemarks are already escaped the above code breaks things as it replaces \" with \ \".

So is there any way I can search and replace " only and ignore \"?

Comment: You'll have to rewrite your question. I understand it's a difficult question to phrase, but the nature of how you've asked it makes it more difficult to understand.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Escaping part of the information changes its meaning. And why would you want to escape in the first place? There are different methods in php to prepare data  for output to different media. `str_replace()` is not one of them.

Comment: Are you doing that to use it in a database query?

Comment: Something is wrong with your code, if only "some" quotes were escaped already.

Comment: @GinoPane No, not necessarily; this is a valid question.  What happens if user (or attacker) submits `...\"  "...`.  The attacker has submitted code (likely bypassing all front-end "security" checks) that has an already escaped quotation mark.

Comment: @TheBobster There are well known routes, depending on your next step -- almost all involve using someone else's battle-hardened libraries. For example, are you inputting to a database?  Then don't even worry about escaping; just use [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: @hunteke Even if that's what he's trying to fix, why not just escape it normally? After all, if I enter `\"` in a field, I don't expect the backslash to be stripped when viewing it later. So no, I don't see a single valid use case for escaping in this way.

Comment: @chocochaos who said anything about stripping?  Submit the content to the next stage _exactly_ as it was entered, and similarly return as such.  Proper escaping is context dependent, and best left to the libraries of each context.  For example, submitting a comment?  Let the comment presentation layer appropriately change the necessary characters.

Comment: @hunteke Whenever you implement partial escaping as OP is requesting, unescaping it will cause data-loss compared to the original. There is no way escaping in this way can ever result in good code.

Comment: @chocochaos that's exactly the point I think myself and others are attempting to make: don't do "partial escaping".  Do proper escaping, which generally means using libraries and battle-hardened code.  Regardless, at this point, the community has spoken, and this question, with currently a -2 score, will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
preg_replace('/(?<!\\)"/', '\"', $data);
```

Honestly though, escaping in this way is ugly. And if you need this, you are already doing something wrong.

You should highly consider refactoring your code to use proper escaping functions for what you are trying to achieve and so you won't  need to worry about double-escaping :)